# How to delete certain elements in a list of list depending on multiple criteria, which includes sum of elements too

Tags: python, list

I have a data like this.

```
[[begin],
[type, 91],
[point, 1450.0, 789.5, 3.5, 2.44207E+08],
[track, 61, 34753.6445, 0.18736, -0.14534, -0.97148, -1],
[track, 2212, 938.2723, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, -1],
[info, 2, 949108, 5.4972E-10],
[track, 18, 7571.8184, -0.10435, -0.18949, -0.98617, -2],
[track, 113, 14058.4375, 0.23803, -0.14617, -0.96087, -2],
[track, 113, 10121.6787, 0.28336, -0.14348, -0.94822, -2],
[track, 2212, 2194.4082, 0.28044, -0.00229, -0.95987, -2],
[track, 21, 1745.5736, 0.30398, -0.25261, -0.91858, -2],
[track, 2212, 939.8723, -0.50622, -0.54921, -0.66492, -2],
[track, 212, 950.5656, -0.97206, -0.19458, 0.13131, -2],
[track, 2212, 2194.4082, 0.28044, -0.00229, -0.95987, 0],
[track, 21, 1745.5736, 0.30398, -0.25261, -0.91858, 0],
[track, 2212, 939.8723, -0.50622, -0.54921, -0.66492, 0],
[track, 212, 950.5656, -0.97206, -0.19458, 0.13131, 0],
[track, 61, 2868.8396, -0.21026, 0.0310, -0.97718, 0],
[track, 11, 1910.0385, -0.08027, -0.21739, -0.97278, 0],
[track, 11, 1944.7386, 0.05074, -0.18072, -0.98222, 0],
[track, -21, 848.2019, -0.13192, -0.59527, -0.79262, 0],
[track, 21, 6132.1333, 0.29963, -0.18552, -0.94129, 0],
[track, -21, 7926.3042, 0.18966, -0.13053, -0.97313, 0],
[track, 21, 4186.8740, 0.38838, -0.12646, -0.91278, 0],
[track, -21, 5964.8052, 0.20810, -0.18427, -0.96587, 0]]
```

In this data I want to leave some lists and write rest to other file.

Conditions:

1. The list which has `list[0]` as `'track'`, `list[1]` as `18` and `list[-1]` as `'-2'`, I want call `list[2]` of that list as `'a'`.
2. All lists with `list[0]` as `'track'` and `list[-1]` as `'0'`, I want to extract information from them; expect for those lists;

   2.1. List with `list[1]` as `61` and one which comes after that until the `sum(list[2])` is equal to `'a'` should be left.

   2.2. The list coming after that should be again taken.

The code I wrote:

```
E_dummy=[]
E_had=[]

for i in event:
    if i[0]=='track':
        if i[6]=='-2':
            if (i[1]=='18' or i[1]=='-18'):
                b=float(i[2])
        if i[6]=='0':

            if (i[1]=='61' or i[1]=='-61'):
                flag='0'
                pass
            if flag=='0':
                E_dummy.append(float(i[2]))
                c=sum(E_dummy)
                if abs(np.subtract(b,c))<=0.5:
                    flag='1'
                    pass


            if flag=='1':
                E_had.append(float(i[2]))`
```

But I did not get the desired result.

Expected lists as output are:

```
[track, 2212, 2194.4082, 0.28044, -0.00229, -0.95987, 0],
[track, 21, 1745.5736, 0.30398, -0.25261, -0.91858, 0],
[track, 2212, 939.8723, -0.50622, -0.54921, -0.66492, 0],
[track, 212, 950.5656, -0.97206, -0.19458, 0.13131, 0],
[track, 21, 6132.1333, 0.29963, -0.18552, -0.94129, 0],
[track, -21, 7926.3042, 0.18966, -0.13053, -0.97313, 0],
[track, 21, 4186.8740, 0.38838, -0.12646, -0.91278, 0],
[track, -21, 5964.8052, 0.20810, -0.18427, -0.96587, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you won't get the desired result is that you're comparing numbers to strings.  The integer `61` in your data can never be equal to the string `'61'` in your `if` statement.

Given your style of data handling, you might consider learning to use a PANDAS data frame or a NumPy array.  This would allow you to treat a column much as a list, which will make some of your logic more direct.